# bin/magento magento 1.7

Tags: magento2

I need run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, but bin folder not exists in `magento` installation.

I have this files and directories:

[image]

How I can run the command?

Answer (score 2):

`bin/magento` is specific to Magento 2 and as such is not part of Magento 1.

Magento 1 will run setup upgrades once the caches have been cleaned automatically.

Comment: Thanks. The web load but not has CSS. How I can do a deploy in Magento 1?